# React not taking initial input type number as 0

Tags: reactjs

React not displaying 0 for input type number. It is working fine and as expected if we uncheck the isInputNum checkbox.

[Demo](https://devfolioco.github.io/react-otp-input/)

Upon googling I found out that this was a known react issue but was fixed. I tried debugging and also tried to set the default value as 0 in that case it works fine.

Below line decides what class should be assigned to Input box:

## File [link](https://github.com/raghavpatnecha/react-otp-input/tree/master/src/lib)

```
 type={isInputNum ? 'number' : 'tel'}
          {...numValueLimits}
          maxLength="1"
          ref={input => {
            this.input = input;
          }}
          disabled={isDisabled}
          value={value ? value : ' '}
```

[Link to Project](https://github.com/raghavpatnecha/react-otp-input)

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

`0` is a falsey value in JavaScript:

```
value={value ? value : ' '}
```

With `value` as `0` this code will always return `' '`;

You need to check if `value` is `undefined`:

```
value={value !== undefined ? value : ' '}
```

Or check for `null` or `undefined`:

```
value={value != null ? value : ' '}
```

Comment: A check for null and undefined would be better e.g. `value != null`

Comment: @MuratKaragöz It is still producing the same output as null. Can you try running the code.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Not really, probably better to include a helper method (e.g. `_.isNil` in lodash) and test both `undefined` and `null` explicitly. Any usage of `==` and `!=` is suspicious.

Comment: @Sulthan suspicious eh? https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isNil.js#L20  :)

Comment: @DavinTryon I tried but still no success, However I have made some tweks in code and now it is taking 0 as first input but doesn't take any additional inputs after that. I have updated the code in link.